# How does Mandrill work?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mandrill

I just set up a Rails app to use Mandrill for sending notification emails (in development environment).  When I signed up for Mandrill, it used my gmail for a username and under the 'sending domain' it has gmail listed. Based on this (and not very comprehensive docs), I assumed that Mandrill would be sending the email `through my` gmail account.

[image]

In my Rails mailer Notifier.rb, I set the default mail address to a fake (i.e. non-existent) name

```
default from: "fakenotrealemail@gmail.com"
```

and when I received test emails from my Rails app using mandrill the emails were sent from 'fakenotrealemail@gmail.com'. Obviously that email address didn't send the emails because it doesn't exist. I'm not sure if Rails will always do that, or what Mandrill's role is.

1. Anyways, if Mandrill's not using my real gmail address (that I signed up with) to send emails, then why is 'gmail' listed as a
   'sending domain.'
2. Once I get the custom domain name for my app (once the app's launched) and sign up for Google business apps to get email with custom domain, is there anything I have to do to get Mandrill to use that? or is it just as simple as using that as the 'default' name in the Notifier.rb class of the Rails app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mandrill automatically adds any domain names that are used for outgoing mail to the Domain list that you are seeing. This is normal.

I should make it clear that Mandrill is NOT using any Gmail server to send you message. The message is being delivered through the Mandrill system alone.

Once you get your custom domain you should begin using that as the "from" address for your emails. This domain will then show up in the domain list.

I highly recommend that you setup the proper DKIM and SPF records in your custom domain DNS records. Mandrill has very clear instructions on how to do this. Just click on the "View DKIM settings" and "View error details" in the domain list.

I recommend you check out the following page for additional information: http://help.mandrill.com/entries/21681347-How-do-I-set-up-sending-domains-

Comment: thanks, but if Mandrill's not using my domain to send the emails (but rather its own system), why does it need DKIM and SPF records?

Comment: why does it need to list gmail as a sending domain if it's not using the gmail address I signed up with?

Comment: DKIM and SPF record are designed to tell the recipient of your email that you have authorized Mandrill server to send mail on your behalf. This is an anti-spam mechanism.

Comment: The gmail address that you signed you with has NOTHING to do with what you are seeing the in the domain list. This list is AUTOMATICALLY populated with any domains that you use as the "from" address in any message you send through the Mandrill system.

Comment: Unfortunately I bought my domain through GoDaddy. Mandrillapp says enabling DKIM and SPF with GoDaddy has to be done with Plesk Panel http://support.godaddy.com/help/article/198/setting-up-dns-with-your-parallels-plesk-panel-9-server-and-domain-with-us  have you done this before? Is that something I install on my computer or directly on my VPS?

Comment: Leahcim, I am new to Mandrill.  I have GoDaddy domains also.  I was having weird problems sending emails.  The link you posted is for people who have dedicated servers.  I was able to add DKIM and SPF using the regular DNS Editor. I went to the Sending Domains section in my account.  When I tested for DKIM and SPF on all my domains it found them.  I hope this will fix my occasional problem receiving my emails using Mandrill.  If not I will need to find another option for my Rails applications.

Comment: @LightBeCorp: are you guys able to setup Mandrill in your Godaddy hosting space? Because i am getting 535 authentication error while using it in my hosting space. But the code works fine in Local Host

Comment: @venkat, sorry I'm just responding. I was on vacation from December 19 until January 11. I am successfully sending emails using Mandrill with my GoDaddy domains. All I did was make the changes to the DNS records on the domain that were mentioned on the Mandrill website to get it working. Note: I'm not hosting my Ruby on Rails websites on GoDaddy.

Answer (score 0):

Mandrill always takes the domain we specify as the custom domain so if you pass `gmail.com` in your `sending domain name` then `mandrill` treats it as `your custom domain`. It will **NOT** send mails through your `gmail` account rather it will send mails according to whatever you provide as your **sending domain** in your case it is **gmail.com**.